# How to separate data to year

Tags: php

i have data sql

- **19**DB
- **18**CA
- **98**CG

how to i seperate to year with php?
be like :

- 20**19**
- 20**18**
- 19**98**

Comment: Cast to integer, then assume something to prepend either 19 or 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the string, extracting the first 2 characters and then guess which is the century to prepend to the string.

I crafted a function doing something like that:

https://onlinephp.io/c/cbda3

```
<?php

echo parseYear("19DB");
echo "\n";
echo parseYear("18CA");
echo "\n";
echo parseYear("98CG");

function parseYear($input){
    $year_parsed = substr($input, 0, 2);

    $year_century = "20";
    if ( intval($year_parsed) > 50 )
        $year_century = "19";
        
    $output = "${year_century}${year_parsed}";
    
    return $output;
}
```